# Validate textfield, allows only letters, '-', and '.'

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my text field validate the text entered into it. At the moment I am telling it to only allow letters a-z and - and.

The current set up is if its invalid it will bring up a cross and if its valid it will bring up a tick.

At the moment though it doesn't check the minimum and maximum characters entered into the text area but I want it to be able to do this, so could someone please show me how to do this please?

So far I have this script but I don't know how to get it to check the minimum and maximum characters in the field, say I want it to have a min of 5 and a max of 60.

The other problem I have is whilst at the moment the validation is working and will bring up a tick if letters a-z and - are entred, and if someone puts in @ or / on its own then it will bring up a cross, but otherwise if someone type 'hello@' then it also validates it and brings up the tick but the @ character should not be allowed.

script:

```
<script>
function validateCname(CnameField){
        var reg = /[A-Za-z\._-]$/;



        if (reg.test(CnameField.value) == false) 
        {
            document.getElementById("emailTick").style.display='none'; // Hide tick if validation Fails
            document.getElementById("emailCross").style.display='block';
            return false;
        }
        if (reg.test(CnameField.value) == true)
        document.getElementById("emailCross").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("emailTick").style.display='block';
        return true;
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="field_cname" name="cname" class="field_cname" onfocus="document.getElementById('field_cname').style.background='#ffffff';" onblur="validateCname(this);">
<div id="emailCross"></div><div id="emailTick"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to:

```
var reg = /^[A-Za-z\._-]{5,60}$/;
```

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, why?

Comment: @AmitJoki you have no delimiter, `45245aaaaa523452` would pass.

Comment: Now I have. Thanks @Karl-AndréGagnon